# Double data result

Tags: sql, database

the project that i'm doing right now is about bartering system which required 2 match making attribute in the same table . The sql query is like below :

```html
SELECT a.itemsid,a.category,a.condition,a.description,a.name,a.seek,a.picture,a.conditionS,a.categoryS,a.studentid 
FROM items a 
INNER JOIN items b 
ON a.name = b.seek 
AND b.name = a.seek
WHERE a.name ='database' and b.name='java'
```

the result from the query is :

[image]

if you notice in the itemsid column the result is twice and have a redundant data. i already try put the group by condition but i have error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. 
Hope anybody can help me with this situation and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying which DBMS you are using, so you will need to test this solution...

The simples way to avoid repetition is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.itemsid,
                a.category,
                a.condition,
                a.description,
                a.name,
                a.seek,
                a.picture,
                a.conditionS,
                a.categoryS,
                a.studentid 
  FROM items a 
INNER JOIN items b 
  ON a.name = b.seek 
 AND b.name = a.seek
WHERE a.name ='database' 
  AND b.name='java'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    a.itemsid,
    a.category,
    a.condition,
    a.description,
    a.name,
    a.seek,
    a.picture,
    a.conditionS,
    a.categoryS,
    a.studentid
FROM
    items a
INNER JOIN items b ON a.name = b.seek
AND b.name = a.seek
AND a.itemsid < b.itemsid
WHERE
    a.name = 'database'
AND b.name = 'java'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
a.itemsid < b.itemsid
```

to either the `ON` clause or the `WHERE` clause.